# Very strange unknown provider error from ui-router

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, mean-stack

I have an unknown provider issue and have tried placing breakpoints to see where it is being caused from. Have also checked my work against other work I have done previously to see if there are any stupid mistakes but can't see any. I'd really appreciate your help.

Here is my attempt at debugging:

[image]

[image]

Has anyone come across this before?

If I need to will post some code.

Thanks

```js
///<reference path="../../../../typings/angular.d.ts" />
///<reference path="loginService.ts" />
module App {
    export function LoginDirective(): ng.IDirective {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/scripts/controllers/common/login.html',
            scope : {},
            controller: 'loginController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true
        };
    }

    export class LoginController {

        static $inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'loginService'];

        public constructor(
        private $scope: ng.IScope, 
        private $http: ng.IHttpService, 
        private spinnerService: any,
        private loginService: LoginService){

        }

    }
}
angular.module("App")
.controller("loginController", App.LoginController)
.directive("logIn", App.LoginDirective);
```

```js
///<reference path="../../../../typings/angular.d.ts" />
///<reference path="_common.ts" />
module App {
    export class LoginService {

        private signedIn: boolean;
        private token: string;

        constructor(signedIn: boolean, token: string) {
            this.signedIn = false;
            this.token = "";
        }
    }
}
angular.module("App")
.service('loginService', App.LoginService);
```

Comment: Post some code, its probably an injection issue in your controller...

Comment: Hi, have posted code, would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Where is angular supposed to find the signedIn and token arguments needed to call the constructor? Why do you have these arguments in the first place, since you ignore them anyway? Also, your controller constructor has 4 arguments, but $inject only has three values.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, so services can't take arguments in their constructors? Thanks

Comment: They can, as long as those are other services or value or constants that can be injected by Angular.